# Extrude in same angle?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I have 2 vertices I would like to extrude, but the previous vertices were not straight vertical or horizontal. I am not sure which angle I extruded them in. Is there anyway to extrude these 2 in the same direction as the previous vertices?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Option 1

If the face you are extruding from is planar one way to do this is to use a custom orientation which you can take from that face and use as a local coordinate system for future operations.

[image]

In the example I already had a "Transform Orientation" named Face, and Blender made a new one called "Face.001" so as not to override the old one.

#### Option 2

Select the edge you want to extrude, change the transform orientation in the tool below, to Normal. Hit Extrude, and press (X,Y, or Z) twice until you see an orientation line that matches the direction you want to translate the extrude edge in.

[image]

Comment: i'll probably return to these and make better descriptions + images, if no-one else does.

Comment: You can use ctrl+alt+space to add a new orientation and alt+space to select then.