# Can a local axis be aligned with an edge?

Tags: edges

I want to align (make parallel) any of the 3 local axes with an edge. How can this be done? Can such an axes system be made available outside the object the edge belongs to?

Comment: see [manual/transform_orientations](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/transform_orientations.html)

Comment: also see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31699/47 (works for Edges too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can have any number of [custom transform orientations](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/transform_orientations.html). You create a transform orientation by selecting either a vertex, edge or face and in the Tool Properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) at the bottom, expand the *Transform Orientations* tab. The plus sign will add a new *orientation* based on the currently selected element in the scene.

It's a good idea to *name* these orientations if you plan to reuse them, else that list can get confusing.

This Transform orientation can then be selected from the drop downs in that same panel, or in the 3dView header. Because they persist in the .blend they can be recalled at any later stage.

Also [see this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31699/47), which covers much of the same

**Limitations**

(Dec 2015) You can't make a Transform Orientation using a Curve Object's *Point* or *Segment*.

Comment: Unfortunately setting the axis using two points does not work with two control points of a NURBS-curve, only with two vertices.

Comment: I do believe i wrote that already.

Comment: God this is SO useful! I just did a loop cut into the direction I wanted the axis to be. Easy.