# Local translation fail due to wrong rotated origin

Tags: modeling

I have messed up with rotation (rotated object in edit mode, not object, and now object's origin rotated in wrong direction and i can't correctly scale my plank)

[image]

[image]

I know that i can simply create new one, but i would like to know how can i reset my origin or model rotation, without creating new object.

P.s. Origin to geometry doesn't help same as geometry to origin.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42998/can-a-local-axis-be-aligned-with-an-edge

Comment: Use normal axes, choose Normal Transform orientation and move faces according to it (press scale axis name twice after entering interactive tools); also it's possible to use another pivot point, e.g. active face to translate according to its space. Changing origin point won't really help here.

Comment: @MrZak tried. I know it is weird, but the normal's angle is slightly different (i know that they have to be perpendicular), so it will work only with relatively short transformation and btw it is not a direct solution.

Comment: Is the scale of the object applied? (Object mode > Ctrl+A > Scale) Using normal axes is one of solutions as you can't use global or local coordinates for the object with applied rotation. Alternative is to snap empty to one of the sides of the object, parent object to it and reset its rotation